Maven release plugin unable to commit files
Setup:
I have a monorepo where there is no top level pom.xml file but there are projects or modules that use maven and spring boot. I also use github actions and each module has its own workflow of building, testing, and releasing artifacts.
Issue:
If you create a PR which contains changes to more than one service and merge it to the main branch which triggers workflows (as many as the changes span), it may happen that you get an error like this in one of the workflows and you have to manually re-run the job after it fails. Here's the error:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.1:prepare (default-cli) on project someProject: Unable to commit files
This happens because the first workflow bumps version of service A and commits it, and service B ends up behind HEAD.
I was thinking of configuring maven release plugin so that it does not complain about detached head, but there does not seem to be such a flag.
What do?
